# How do you send data from one observable into another?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I don’t know why this is not simpler; I know `from()` creates new observable - not what I want; given two observable A and B, when I call `a.next(foo)` I want subscribers to b to pick up on it. Not necessarily the other way around. Other than a verbose subscribe, is there any way to do so?

Comment: What does B have to do with A in this context?

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to make your question more specific.  Read [ask].

Comment: I don’t know why this is not simpler. It should be pretty easy. For example: `const a = from[1,2,3]; const b = a.pipe(map(v = v + 1));` b will emit 2,3,4 using values it got from a when subscribed.

Comment: As mentioned, please clarify the question.

Comment: please share proper code which you are practicing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a` is a subject based on your example, you can declare `b` by setting up a pipe to `a`.

```
const a = new Subject<unknown>();

const b = a.pipe(
  map(foo=>{
    // do something with foo and return a value
  })
)

a.next(foo) 
// b will now do something with foo and emits the return value to the subscriber
```

Alternately, if `b` has its own observable that you need to return, there are several operators you can use to accomplish this. The most basic example would be `switchMap()`.

```
const b = a.pipe(
  switchMap(foo=>{
    // do something with foo and return an observable
  })
)

a.next(foo) 
// b will now do something with foo and will return an observable that will be subscribed by the subscriber.
```

In either scenario, when you have a subscriber to `b`, any new values emitted from `a` will cause `b` to react and emit its new value.

```
const bSub = b.subscribe(value=>console.log(value));
a.next(foo) // bSub will console log new value based on foo
a.next(bar) // bSub will console log new value based on bar
```

Comment: To be specific -- assume that both a and b are independently created; "b" is not something you create to solve the problem, its another subject that exists already.